# Magento 2 - productCollection to json

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection, json

In a `.phtml` template file I have loaded a `productCollection` using `objectManager` as follow:

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$values = [14];
$conditionType = "in";
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter([$conditionType => $values]);
```

I'd like to print a json with all the products, showing only the following product attributes:

- Name
- Sku
- Link to img

What's the "Magento way" to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the correct/best way, but after some researches I got it working as follow:

```
$collection_to_encode = array();

// this is needed to get image URL
$imagehelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');


foreach( $productCollection as $product )
{
    $product_to_encode = array();

    $productsid = $product->getId();
    $productsname = $product->getName();
    $productsimageurl = $imagehelper->init($product, 'category_page_list')->getUrl();


    $product_to_encode[] = array(
        'id' => $productsid,
        'name' => $productsname,
        'image' => $productsimageurl );

    $collection_to_encode = array_merge($product_to_encode, $collection_to_encode);
}

$encoded_products = json_encode($collection_to_encode);

echo $encoded_products;
```